# Build error in oculus native mobile sdk version 1.9.0

Tags: python, build, sdk, oculus

I am trying to develop a native gear `VR application` in `android studio` using `oculus native mobile SDK version 1.9.0`. On running the `VR` samples enclosed within the `SDK`, I ran into the error mentioned below and the build failed.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.9.0\bin\scripts\build\ovrbuild_keystore.py", line 86, in 
>       genDebugKeystore()
>
> File "C:\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.9.0\bin\scripts\build\ovrbuild_keystore.py", line 84, in genDebugKeystore
>       debug_props['storepass'], debug_props['keypass'], replace=False)
>
> File "C:\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.9.0\bin\scripts\build\ovrbuild_keystore.py", line 71, in create_keystore
>       return execfn(cmd)
>
> File "C:\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.9.0\bin\scripts\build\ovrbuild_keystore.py", line 82, in 
>       create_keystore(lambda x: ovrbuild.call(x),
>
> File "ovrbuild.py", line 169, in call
>       gradleTask = "clean" if command_options.should_clean else "assembleDebug" if command_options.is_debug_build else "assembleRelease"
>   NameError: global name 'command_options' is not defined
>
> :VrSamples:Native:VrTemplate:Projects:Android:genDebugKeystore FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> *Where:
>   Script 'C:\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.9.0\VrApp.gradle' line: 314
>
> *What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':VrSamples:Native:VrTemplate:Projects:Android:genDebugKeystore'.
>   Process 'command 'C:\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.9.0/bin/scripts/build/ovrbuild_keystore.py.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Could anyone of you help me to solve this error?

This error is also present in `oculus SDK version 1.7.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem. Same output and everything.

After tracing the issue down for hours, I finally found my problem to be that my PATH did not include the java bin directory. The error was being caused because the keytool.exe program could not be reached.

On Windows 10, right click on This PC, select Advanced System Settings, select Environment Variables. In the System variables window on the lower half of the screen, find the Path variable. Ensure the java bin directory is in the list.

In my case I had to add:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin

The problem was not immediately corrected. I still had Android Studio open. I shut down the program and restarted the computer. After reboot and opening Android Studio again, everything started to build!

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: I'm a little confused at this solution.  I think actually the problem is that there are two competing versions of Java in the path, your system jdk from oracle, and then the OpenJDK that is installed by AndroidStudio.  In fact, I'm looking in my install path, and it's something like: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre  .  What is strange is there is a second layer of jre under the jre dir.

Comment: As a possible solution, I'm going to look at running from the command line gradle commands to see if I can debug the root cause.  I think you are on the right track with the JDK in the path, just possibly not as one expects, the wrong JDK might be picked up and that's triggering a failure.

Comment: The actual root cause can be discovered by running the failing utility program: C:\ovr_sdk_mobile_1.9.0/bin/scripts/build/ovrbuild_keystore.py.bat .  It will fail with a  "keytool" not found error.   Hint: keytool is in the jre or jdk directory, but presumably this needs to be on the PATH, per the answer.  Make sure you have a "keytool" on your path, and the easiest way is to set the path to your JRE or JDK.  Note, this may cause other problems with other software, but well written scripts should attempt to find the right version of the JRE or JDK needed.